# Error when reload page with API and React Hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, react-redux, react-hooks

I have this component, which works fine, but only once. If I reload, I have a undefined error.

My component :

```
import { UidContext } from "../components/AppContext"
import React, { useContext, useEffect, useState } from "react"
import axios from "axios"

export default function Balance() {
    const uid = useContext(UidContext)
    const [userWallet, setUserWallet] = useState(null)

    useEffect(() => {
        if (uid !== null) {
            axios.get(`${process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL}api/balance/${uid}`)
                .then((res) => setUserWallet(res.data[0]))
        }
    }, [uid])

    return (
        <section>
            {userWallet.salaire1}
        </section>
    )
}
```

The result at first load :
[userWallet result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h64P5.png)

and then, I have this error :

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'salaire1' of null
```

Why would a console.log work, and not in the JSX ?

Thank you

Comment: you have to check if userwallet is fetched or not and then render it

Comment: I guess uid is blank when reloaded? Check with console.log()

Comment: @GündoğduYakıcı if I log uid, I get one null and 2 uid when I reload

Comment: @AliNajafi if I log the data, the fetch is fine. I get the data

Comment: easiest way is adding question mark op ```{userWallet?.salaire1}```

Comment: @cybercoder yes, it works now. I didn't know this way, what it its name, so I can read about it ?

Comment: @JohanBRAZILLIER ```optional chaining```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use optional chaining with `userWallet?.salaire1` . or handle with ternary conditional like
`userWallet.salaire1 && userWallet.salaire1`
In this case you have predefined state value `userWallet` is null. hence the UI couldn't render undefined property therefore your screen is blank and promp error

actually your console work but it the log return twice, the first one is null then the data shown.

I hope my answer can help to understand your issue :)

Comment: It works with userWallet?.salaire1. But why do I get a null and then the data ? Did I do something wrong ?

Comment: actually you didn't wrong, but this is state management concept, every single state there is initial value. and you have been defined with null value. also in this case you fetching data from other resources and type of that is Promise. I think the proper/common ways to handle that, you need to put loading state to prevent null or white screen on your app